# Flyspell: is it possible to ignore words based on pattern?

Tags: emacs, spell-checking

I would really like to disable flyspell checking of camel-cased words - most of the times they aren't valid English. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the variable `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` to a function that returns `nil` if point is at a camel-cased word.

Note that this variable automatically becomes buffer-local when set, so setting it with a plain `setq` in your .emacs file wouldn't work.  Set it from a mode hook instead, e.g.:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate 'my-new-function)))
```

(replacing `my-new-function` with the name of your camel-case detecting function)